# While Loop that increments a variable to a point

Tags: c++, while-loop

My goal for this program is to get input from the user for value 'y' and then multiply that value by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and then print the 10 results. Right now, when the user enters a value for 'y', the program just returns a list of zeros. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    x = 0;
    z = x * y;
    cout << "enter y" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    while (x < 10) {
        cout << z << endl;
        x = x + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Enable more compiler warnings and re-read the first few chapters of your C++ book.

Comment: You aren't even changing variable `z` in your loop. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you don't actually calculate `z` inside the loop, so it will always be the value you calculated outside the loop. Statements and expressions can't be done retroactively.

But you have a worse problem than that, because you use `y` before you initialize it, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the location of the y input to be before the calculation of z that should be inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

The statement z = x * y should be inside your while loop for it to work.
What is happening now is that,each time it is printing the same value of z which is calculated initially as x(which is 0) and y(which is some garbage value as it has not been initialized) to give 0

Answer (score 0):

The first problem occurring in your code is that try to assign z by multiplying x with y, but y is not assigned to a certain value => ERROR! That means you should get your user input before you assign z.

You may wonder why you get ten outputs of '0': Inside the loop you only print the value assigned to z to the console but z is already assigned before and not changed during the repetition.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    x = 0;
    z = x * y;                 // y is never assigned to a value
    cout << "enter y" << endl;
    cin >> y;                  // y got assigned here!
    while (x < 10) {
        cout << z << endl;     // z stays the same in the loop
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```